# how to access variable from onother class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a class name project and project2

```
public class project1 extends sprite
{
    var window1:camera=new camera()
}

class project2 extends HomeUI implements IView
{
    var window2:camera=new camera()
}
```

i want to acces the variable window2 on class project1
can someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a method in project1, create a new project2,
then just access it since it's public.

Example:

```
public class project1 extends sprite
{
    var window1:camera=new camera();
    public void doSomething(){
        var project2object:project2 = new project2();
        var window2:camera = project2object.window2;
        //and here you can do stuff with window2
    }
}
```

There's also a couple problems with your code - Namely that sprite needs to be Sprite...
that project2 needs to be a public class... And I think the classes Project1 and Project2 should be capitalized.